# How can I prevent damage to fire sprinkler heads in workshop?

Tags: product-recommendation, fire-sprinkler

My new condo has a standard heat-activated fire sprinkler system.  In the living areas the sprinkler heads are completely recessed into the ceiling but unfortunately in the garage, which I also plan to use as a wood shop, they are only partly recessed.  Even worse, several of the sprinkler heads in the garage are in places where it will be very easy to bump (messy) or even walk into (messy AND painful).   For example, there are sprinkler heads mounted underneath the top half of an interior stairwell which sticks out into the garage space.

Obviously I cannot disable the sprinkler heads.  What are the best strategies for protecting them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get [sprinkler head cages](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sprinkler%20head%20cage#q=sprinkler%20head%20cage&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&ei=Ssk3TsGtCM2_gQfK7qSaAg&sa=X&oi=product_result_group&ct=image&resnum=3&ved=0CFYQzAMwAg&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=fbefa1fed8dcf62f&biw=1188&bih=833) to protect the sprinkler heads from damage.  Some have bright colors (easier to spot and avoid) and somewhat rounded edges which probably would hurt less if you bumped your head into them.

Comment: I'll give them a shot...